# Accessing organisational webmap using downloaded Basic Viewer of ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, viewer

I have downloaded the [Basic Viewer](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f232cac140a8495f9990cc9d2bb66dd9) of ArcGIS Online (AGOL) to my web- and ArcGIS Server within my organisation. Now I want that copied basicviewer to access a webmap on agol that I made accessible to a few internal groups. The webmap is not published to the general public. I notice that to logon (in person, with a browser) to the org. data of my company I need to logon to a specific URL, not the general AGOL url.

What do I need to do to fill in the index.html file of this basic viewer in order to access this webmap ?

I cannot find a place in the javascript to add usernames and passwords, or code to ask it from me. And I do not understand what a proxy is in the AGOL context. I have not found a relevant blog on organisational versus public use of AGOL (these blogs are often about old or other viewer versions, with other coding styles and technologies). I seek an example for an Organisation-internal situation.

I tested my copied basic viewer with a generally published web ID on AGOL, and that works. But I want to use my own (organisation-internal) AGOL webmaps of course.

This is a snippet from index.html where I think I need to fill in the connection details.

```
    dojo.ready(function(){
    i18n = dojo.i18n.getLocalization("esriTemplate","template");
    var  defaults = {
    //The ID for the map from ArcGIS.com
    webmap: "e7bd1f2f1eab47f2856c108dcf25f56b",
    //Modify this to point to your sharing service URL if you are using the portal
    sharingurl: "http://stedin.maps.arcgis.com",//for example: "http://www.arcgis.com",
    //The id for the web mapping application item that contains configuration info - in most
    ////When editing you need to specify a proxyurl (see below) if the service is on a different domain
    //Specify a proxy url if you will be editing, using the elevation profile or have secure services or web maps that are not shared with everyone.
    proxyurl: "",
    //cases this will be null.
    appid: "",
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can see it in something else unless it is shared.

It wouldn't make sense to let someone chose to share a map or not if you could easily copy the map id from the code behind.